# Portlet JSR286 How to call portlets found in different war on Websphere 6

Tags: java, spring-mvc, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I am new to portlet, basically I have a login portlet and a menu portlet each portlet in a different war. I need to be able to open the login portlet when it is selected from the menu portlet.It is a Spring MVC application.

I have read about eventing in portlet but haven't seen any example when for instance PortletA is in one war and is calling Portlet B in another one.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Is there any free online tutorial that can help?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Event-based_inter-portlet_communication_with_IBM_WebSphere_Portal_and_JSR286) is very basic and effective resource to start with for IPC.